# Cloning only the filled portion of a read only raw data HDD source (without source partition resizing)

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, backup, clone

I often copy raw data from HDD's with FAT32 partitions at the file level. I would like to switch to bitwise cloning this raw data that consists of thousands of 10MiB files that are sequentially written across a single FAT32 partition.

The idea is on the large archival HDD, have a small partition which contains a shadow directory structure with symbolic links to separate raw data image partitions. Each additional partition being the aforenoted raw data, but sized to only the size consumed on the source drive. The number of raw data files on each source drive can be in the tens up through the tens of thousands.

i.e.: `[[sdx1][--sdx2--][-------------sdx3------------][--------sdx4--------][-sdx5-][...]]`

Where 'sdx1' = directory of symlinks to sdx2, sdx3, sdx4, ... such that the user can browse to multiple partitions but it appears to them as if they're just in subfolders.

Optimally I'd like to find *both* a Linux and a Windows solution. If the process can be scripted or a software solution that exists can step through a standard workflow, that'd be best. The process is almost always 1) Insert 4 HDD's with raw data 2) Copy whatever's in them 3) Repeat. Always the same drive slots and process.

AFAIK, in order to clone a source partition without cloning all the free space, one conventionally must resize the source HDD partition first. Since I can't alter the source HDD in any way, how can I get around that?

One way would be clone the entire source partition (incl. free space) and resize the target backup partition afterward, but that's *not* going to work out because of all the additional time that would take.

The goal is to retain bitwise accuracy and to save time (`dd` runs about 200MiB/s whereas `rsync` runs about 130MiB/s, however also needing to copy a ton of blank space every time makes the whole perk moot). I'd also like to be running with some kind of `--rescue` flag so when bad clusters are hit on the source drive it just behaves like `clonezilla` and just writes `????????` in place of the bad clusters. I know I said "retain bitwise accuracy" but a bad cluster's a bad cluster.

If you think one of the COTS or GOTS software like EaseUS, AOMEI, Paragon and whatnot are able to clone partitions as I've described please point me in the right direction. If you think there's some way I can `dd` it up with some script which sizes up the source, makes the right size target partition, then modifies the target FAT to its correct size, chime in I'd love many options and so would future people with a similar use case to mine that stumble on this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fit you, but is very simple.
Syncthing **https://syncthing.net/** will sync the content of 2 or more folders, works on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but thanks. I'd like to do the transfers at a partition clone level.